# Question about Rails, Haml, and Forms

Tags: ruby-on-rails, haml

```
  .section
  .title
    Subscription

  .body
    = form_tag(:action => subscribe_url, :method => :post)
      = @plans.each do |p|
        %tr= p[:blurb]
        %tr= p[:price]
      .spacer
      = submit_tag( 'Subscribe', :class => 'button ok' )

    %p
    %br
    Note: If you wish to cancel your subscription, please
    -# link_to  "contact Customer Support", "http://support.jobfully.com"
```

The error we're seeing is this:
/home/mei/Jobfully/app/views/subscriptions/list.html.haml:21: syntax error, unexpected keyword_ensure, expecting $end

Extracted source (around line #21):

18:     %br
19:     Note: If you wish to cancel your subscription, please
20:     -# link_to  "contact Customer Support", "http://support.jobfully.com"

Any suggestions about what we're doing wrong here`enter code here` would be much appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

I don't know if it's directly related but `form_tag` should be

```
- form_tag(:action => subscribe_url, :method => :post) do
```

and your each loop should be

```
- @plans.each do |p|
```

There's a lot of, what I would call, 'weirdness' going on in the haml you've posted above. By this, I really mean that you have tags that will just be completely empty, such as `.section` and `%p` since there is nothing nested underneath them. I would try cutting out as much as you can and start rebuilding the haml file piece by piece.

Comment: A lot of the weirdness was due to incompleteness. The syntax you showed here worked, I think that we were mixing a few different forms of the tag together when we shouldn't have.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
%br
%p
  Note: If you wish to cancel your subscription, please
  = link_to  "contact Customer Support", "http://support.jobfully.com"
```